# How to create a flat pattern out of a mesh

Tags: cad

I have a mesh representing a folded paper that a create from Fusion 360. I can export it to STL.

I want it to be flatten out so that I can cut it with a lasercutter and then refold it.

Fusion 360 doesn't seem to can do that. I imported the STL on Blender but I didn't really a good solution, but maybe I don't know this program well enough.

What would be the best way?

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin in Blender that is pre-installed and just have to be enable. A tutorial can be found [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/export-paper-model/476597#post1627111).

Answer (score 0):

If blender isn't your cuppa, you can use [Pepakura](https://tamasoft.co.jp/pepakura-en/) to create flat "unfolding" from an STL. It's possible the free version of Pepakura will not perform this magic, but the program cost is quite low (US$38) when one considers the effort involved in creating this software.

[image: pepakura home page graphic]